# How to display a few line from the last few lines for a given number of files?

Tags: linux, grep, find, tail

I have a folder with many different files.
I want to display a specific line from the last 100 line of a list of files.

So far I have tried both Grep and Tail but neither gave me exactly what I want:


Example: the folder has the following files:

- file_1.txt
- file_2.txt
- file_3.txt
- other_file.txt
- other_file2.txt

Content of **file_n.txt** is:

- line 88: test_result: 18209102
- line 89: good bye
- ......
- line 98: test_result: 18202232
- line 99: good bye

Goal:
Only list **test_result** from last 10 lines of each **file_n.txt** (line 90 to line 99)

What I have tried so far:

```
tail -n 10 file_* | grep test_result
```

The above display almost what I needed but I also  need the file name for each result comes from, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in file_*
do
    echo "$f"
    tail -n 10 "$f" | grep test_result
done
```

Comment: this worked wonderful. Instead of using echo, I used printf, this puts result behind each file name, making it easier to process the data.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE:

```
$ seq 20 > file1
$ seq 30 > file2

$ awk '/5/{hits[FNR]=$0} ENDFILE{for (i=FNR-10;i<=FNR;i++) if (i in hits) print FILENAME, hits[i]; delete hits}' file1 file2
file1 15
file2 25
```

The above prints all occurrences of the number `5` in the last 10 lines of each input file.

Comment: Good one! Congrats on your 80K :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like :

```
tail -n10 file* |grep -e '==>' -e 'test_result'
```

This works because by default tail when used with globs (*) will print the filename like bellow:

```
$ tail -n10 file*
==> file5 <==
home
help
variables
compatibility
#modelines

==> file6 <==
[ $# != 2 ] && echo ok;

==> file7 <==
11
```

Mind that this will print the filenames that do not match like:

```
==> file1 <==
==> file2 <==
==> file3 <==
test_result: XXXX
==> file4 <==
```

This behavior may or may not be acceptable (personally i would like to know the files that do not match test_result)

Comment: This worked, though I prefer the result and its file name on the same line. 'If ' statement worked wonderful for such purpose.

Comment: Add `/dev/null` to the arg list (`tail -n10 file* /dev/null`) so you get file names output even if the globbing only matches 1 real file name. Otherwise if `file*` only matches 1 file name then tail won't output that file name. That's a trick from before `grep` had a `-H` argument...